# SQL combine data but keep record

Tags: sql

Hi I'm learning SQL and stuck in this problem

I have a table like this

```
┌──────┬────────┐
│ name │ class  │
├──────┼────────┤
│ Alex │ Math   │
├──────┼────────┤
│ Tony │ Math   │
├──────┼────────┤
│ Tony │ Physic │
├──────┼────────┤
│ Mile │ Physic │
└──────┴────────┘
```

I want to combine the classes for each person in new column like below. How can I do that?

```
┌──────┬───────────────┐
│ name │ classcombined │
├──────┼───────────────┤
│ Alex │ Math          │
├──────┼───────────────┤
│ Tony │ Math-Physic   │
├──────┼───────────────┤
│ Tony │ Math-Physic   │
├──────┼───────────────┤
│ Mile │ Physic        │
└──────┴───────────────┘
```

Explaination: because Tony has 2 classes Math and Physic, so in the new table I want to combine the classname but still keep 2 Tony in the record

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your using dbms?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Are you really sure about this datamodel? How are you going to delete a class? Or count the number of classes?

Comment: Your starting data model is a good normalised model.  Your desired new model is a SQL Anti-Pattern, and in 99% of cases you should not be using it.

Comment: Do you want to update the current table, create a new table or just a select query? Also tag your question with the database that you use.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would do this with one row per name, using a string aggregation operator.  You haven't specified the database, so I'll use the SQL standard operator `listagg()`:

```
select name, listagg(class, '-') within group (order by class)
from t
group by name;
```

If you actually want this *per row* (i.e. repeating the value), then I would suggest a subquery:

```
select name,
       (select listagg(t2.class, '-') within group (order by class)
        from t t2
        where t2.name = t.name
       ) as classes
from t;
```

Note that databases tend to have bespoke functions for string aggregation.  Common names are `string_agg()` and `group_concat()`.